# This 11.10 release of ubuntu is very unstable

Tags: 11.10

why doesn't ICEAuthority recognize me?
'"    "   chromium or audit configuration open anymore?
is this OS always so unstable? 
Why are there so many copies of one thing? 
My mouse is not working right.

Comment: They're going to mark this as "closed", I don't need to be magician to guess it. But I agree with you. I stopped using 11.10 64Bit and will wait for the next release in order to perform a new clean install. Even the Upgrade fails.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your questions can be better addressed if you post them separately. Thanks!

Comment: Did you upgraded or did a clean install?

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo many of us would like to see a real question, in the form which can be addressed. Making statements is not the same as asking a question.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo it is a highly subjective question. I have never had issues with Ubuntu in terms of stability, outside of the times I've used the development version (and that is almost required to be unstable!)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand the question, but no, Ubuntu is usually very stable. Ubuntu has just been through a massive upgrade of platforms, though, so the previous version and this one is naturally not as stable as 10.04, for instance, which is based on a ten year old platform. Bugs are fixed all the time, of course, so if you report one, chances are the problem will be fixed. But it is important that you provide as much detail as you possibly can. And this is not the place for it. Bugs are reported on http://launchpad.net.

Comment: Pretending not to understand the question may be easier than saying: "yes, you must change your definition of 'stable' to: fix everything on each release". But I can see clearly that the question remains and many of us would love to have a "new release" that does not forces us to fix all the things that we fixed in the previous release. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I am not the owner of the question but he should accept this as "the best answer" because of it is gaining upvotes. Yeah! That's the Ubuntu way!

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo The problem is that this question is asking for too many unrelated things and does not provide enough details about the current setup. Questions like these [can cause major headaches once split](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2005/18612). Also, we try to keep questions separate so others looking for answers to specific problems don't have to wade through a lot of other irrelevant information to try and find the solutions they need.

Comment: If you can translate this for me? why doesn't ICEAuthority recognize me? '" " chromium or audit configuration open anymore? I have no idea what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once and was a bad upgrade then I format my drive and did a clean install now problem solved.